# Typescript and HighCharts

Tags: typescript, highcharts

I have the following json that's returned from a C# web api as a name value pair.

```
{
        {
            "Grouping": "Label0",
            "Count": 71
        },
        {
            "Grouping": "Label1",
            "Count": 44
        },
        {
            "Grouping": "Label2",
            "Count": 18
        },
        {
            "Grouping": "Label3",
            "Count": 34
        }        

}
```

I need to cast this data set to support a highchart pie chart. The pie chart requires data in the form of

```
{
  name: <>,
  y: <>,
  drilldown: <>
}
```

How can I cast the retrieved Name value pair into the expected json for highchart? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always parse the received data to match the date format in highcharts: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing

```
var data = [{
    "yearmonth": '2019 - 01',
    "sales": 30
  }, {
    "yearmonth": '2019 - 02',
    "sales": 66
  }, {
    "yearmonth": '2019 - 03',
    "sales": 52
  }],
  parsedData = [];

data.forEach(element => {
  parsedData.push({
    name: element.yearmonth,
    y: element.sales
  });
});
```

A simple example:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fsvrmd3u/

Comment: Can you mark this as the correct answer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, all set. BTW, I posted another question regarding refresh. No sure if you can help there. Thanks